# discord.js Counting command with webhooks

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i'm new in StackOverflow. 
I need  counting command for my discord bot ([discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/))...

I need that when the user starts counting for example 1, then the bot will delete his message and change the webhook to his name and avatar and send his message and the variable will increase by 1...

This is what I got, but there is an error :(

```js
client.on('message', ({message, channel, content, member}) => {
   if (channel.id === 'channel_id') {
     let webhookClient = new Discord.WebhookClient('webhook_id', 'webhook_token');
     let count = 0;
    if (member.user.bot) return
    if (Number(content) === count + 1) {
      webhookClient.send(count, {
          username: content.author.username,
          avatarURL: content.author.displayAvatarURL()
        });
      count++
    }
   }
})
```

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

And I would also like the bot to delete all messages that are not associated with the counter, such as words or emoji ... ("hello", "")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the author's username and avatarURL you need to:

```
username: message.author.username
avatarURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL()
```

Something like this should work:

```
client.on('message', async message =>{
    
    if (message.channel.id === 'channel_id') {
     let webhookClient = new Discord.WebhookClient('webhook_id', 'webhook_token');
     let count = 0;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (Number(message.content) === count + 1) {
      webhookClient.send(count, {
          username: message.author.username,
          avatarURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL()
        });
      count++
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: hmm i tried it and a new error appears.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined

Comment: That means that your message object is null, so you need to check your client.on message event why its returning a null message object.

Comment: uh... How i can check it? (im new in discord.js)

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I got another problem: the bot doesn't count more than 1 - screenshot https://prnt.sc/zi1pyv
And also if you write 1 again, he writes again 1. How can this be fixed? thanks again

Comment: Yes cause count is a local variable. You need to save it externally into a JSON file or a Database and retrieve it from there each time.

Comment: Hm... Can you say please how i can read the value... or something..?
Thats what im make...
https://pastebin.com/FP32FZXr

Comment: Instead of let count = 0; You need to read that data from the JSON file.

Comment: Omg it works !! Thank you very much, but ... I would also like somehow one user to write 1, and another user should write 2, but so that 2 is not counted to the first user and his message is deleted ... Is it possible to do this?